# What is the Chai Assertions equivalent of Python's unittest.TestCase.assertIn(actual, seq)?

Tags: javascript, python, tdd, chai

I have a function that should return one of three values (Let's say 'A', 'B' or 'C'). I want to verify that when this function has been called the return value is one of those things.

If I were writing this as a test in a Python TestCase I might use syntax like:

```
self.assertIn(myFn(), {'A', 'B', 'C'})
```

The first argumet is the function I'm trying to test. The second argument is a set containing the valid answers. All I want to do is assert that the output of myFn() needs to be one of these three specified values. Anything else should cause the test to fail.

But what's the Chai equivalent of this statement?

Chai is a JavaScript assertions library. I'm not asking how to do this in Python (since I've actually given valid Python syntax in this question). Your answer should be valid JavaScript (or CoffeeScript), which shows the Chai syntax which is equivalent to the Python syntax in this question.

Comment: @Alex, you've given me the syntax for defining a list - that's not equivalent to the Python syntax I gave in my question. I'm somewhat confused!

Comment: Alex - thanks again but could you please explain your thinking? I'm trying to write a Chai assertion, but you have just referred me to the equivalent documentation from Python's testing library. The highlighted section shows the same syntax that I originally gave in my question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question. As originally written, it was ambiguous -- Chai is also a Python mocking framework, and you didn't originally clarify which one you wanted, which is why the answers you were getting weren't doing what you want.